# How could I best work around the function comparison TypeError in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make program which automatically determines the cheapest method of mailing a package based on its weight.

The code is refusing to run however as I keep getting the following `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'`.

I tried turning the functions into floats with:
`if float(cost_ground) < float(cost_drone) and float(cost_ground) < float(cost_premium):`
But this returns the following `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'`.

Any advice and/or explanation on how to solve this?

Here is the full code:

```py
def cheapest(weight):
  def cost_ground(weight):
    if weight <= 2:
      return float((weight * 1.50) + 20)
    elif weight <= 6:
      return float((weight * 3.00) + 20)
    elif weight <= 10:
      return float((weight * 4.00) + 20)
    else:
      return float((weight * 4.75) + 20)
  def cost_drone(weight): 
    if weight <= 2:
      return float((weight * 4.50))
    elif weight <= 6:
      return float((weight * 9.00)) 
    elif weight <= 10:
      return float((weight * 12.00))
    else:
      return float((weight * 14.25))
  def cost_premium(weight):
    return 125.00  
  if cost_ground < cost_drone and cost_ground < cost_premium:
   return "Ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + cost_ground
  if cost_drone < cost_ground and cost_drone < cost_premium:
    return "Drone shipping is the cheapest at $" + cost_drone
  if cost_premium < cost_ground and cost_premium < cost_drone:
    return "Premium ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + cost_premium
```

Comment: Yes. You need to ***call*** the functions. Like `cost_ground(weight)`... You should probably benefit from going over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial), specifically about [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function when *called* needs to be given it's parameters. The only situation where a function can be called without any parameters is if the function itself takes *no parameters*. The following code should make that clear:

```
def function_a():
    print("No parameters required.")

def function_b(parameter_1,parameter_2):
    return parameter_1 + parameter_2
function_a()
function_b()
```

Calling the first function without any parameters will not produce any errors however calling the second function *will* produce an error since it takes two parameters and it has been given none.

In your code, you are not passing a parameter to the functions. Defined by your ownself, `cost_ground()` takes a `weigth` parameter. When you are calling that function, you are calling it without the parameter.
Hence it should be:

```
if float(cost_ground(weight)) < float(cost_drone(weight)) and float(cost_ground(weight)) < float(cost_premium(weight)):
```

In addition to this when you return the values,  you must convert values from `float` to `string` as follows:

```
return "Ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + str(cost_ground(weight))
```

Otherwise it will given the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Full code is given below, it should work fine now.

```
def cheapest(weight):
  def cost_ground(weight):
    if weight <= 2:
      return float((weight * 1.50) + 20)
    elif weight <= 6:
      return float((weight * 3.00) + 20)
    elif weight <= 10:
      return float((weight * 4.00) + 20)
    else:
      return float((weight * 4.75) + 20)
  def cost_drone(weight):
    if weight <= 2:
      return float((weight * 4.50))
    elif weight <= 6:
      return float((weight * 9.00))
    elif weight <= 10:
      return float((weight * 12.00))
    else:
      return float((weight * 14.25))
  def cost_premium(weight):
    return 125.00
  if float(cost_ground(weight)) < float(cost_drone(weight)) and float(cost_ground(weight)) < float(cost_premium(weight)):
   return "Ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + str(cost_ground(weight))
  if cost_drone < cost_ground and cost_drone < cost_premium:
    return "Drone shipping is the cheapest at $" + str(cost_drone(weight))
  if cost_premium < cost_ground and cost_premium < cost_drone:
    return "Premium ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + str(cost_premium(weight))
```

Answer (score 2):

`cost_ground`, `cost_drone` and `cost_premium` are all functions. There is no concept of one function being greater than another. For example:

```
>>> def f1(): return 1
>>> def f2(): return 2
>>> f1 > f2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'
```

You meant to *call* the functions and to do that you need to use parentheses and optionally arguments as defined by the functions. Using the above functions:

```
>>> f1() > f2()
False
```

This works because it is the return values of the functions that is being compared, not the function objects.

For example, `cost_ground` is defined as accepting an argument named `weight` so that needs to be supplied when calling the function; `cost_ground(5)` will return a float value 35.0.

So you should be doing this:

```
weight = 5
if cost_ground(weight) < cost_drone(weight) and cost_ground(weight) < cost_premium(weight):
    return f"Ground shipping is the cheapest at ${cost_ground(weight)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

cost_premium and cost_ground are functions and not numbers. They should be called in such a way that they evaluate to numbers:

instead of
`ìf cost_premium < cost_ground ...` do `if cost_premium(weight) < cost_ground(weight) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the actual Python function objects rather than the results returned by those functions. In Python, a function name can be treated like a variable if the function is not invoked. You've already got the *weight* argument passed to the top-level function `cheapest()`, so pass it to functions. So your code:

```
  if cost_ground < cost_drone and cost_ground < cost_premium:
     return "Ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + cost_ground
```

becomes:

```
  if cost_ground(weight) < cost_drone(weight) and cost_ground(weight) < cost_premium(weight):
      return "Ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + cost_ground
```

Also note that comparisons like these can be ganged together. So a simpler way of writing the `if` line of the code would be:

```
   if cost_drone(weight) > cost_ground(weight) < cost_premium(weight):
```